# All my subdomains linked to the same DocRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, subdomain, virtualhost

i wand to enable some sub-domains in my apche2. I created some vhost files but i always get the same page on every sub.domain.
If i enabled only one of the files i get the page of this DocumentRoot...

Here my configs:

*apache2.conf (partly):*

```
# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf
```

*sites-available/domain.de:*

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName domain.de
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /home/..../
      <Directory /home/..../>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all

         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

*sites-available/webmail.domain.de:*

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName webmail.domain.de
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/webmail/
      <Directory /var/www/webmail/>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
      </Directory>
     ErrorLog /var/www/webmail/log/mail.domain.de.error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug
   </VirtualHost>
```

I had enabled them with a2ensite and restart apache2 as well.

In my DNS Configs i had a A record for host "*" to my IP

System Info:
Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)
Apache/2.2.22

Can anyone help me?
Thanks for the trouble!

Comment: So you get content from /var/www/webmail/ on domain webmail.domain.de only if VirtualHost for domain.de is disabled? Otherwise you see contents of domain.de? Didn't you paste the whole VirtualHost configs?

Comment: If I disabled all vhost i get content from /var/www/ on domain.de and on very subdomain xyz.domain.de

Comment: [sorry enter pressed] ... If is enabled sites-available/domain.de I get the content of this DocRoot on domain.de and on every subdomain. If I enable "webmail.domain.de" and "domain.de" vhosts I get die main (domain.de) content also on webmail.domain.de. If is only enable "webmail.domain.de" i get the webmail page on domain.de and on every subdomain (webmail.domain.de as well)

Comment: Very interesting. Are you sure you have no `ServerAlias` directives? Please show ls `sites-enabled`. Also in sites-enabled try to rename `webmail.domain.de` to `000-webmail.domain.de` and `domain.de` to `001-domain.de` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried this.  `:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls -> 000-webmail.domain.de  001-domain.de` . Now is always get the webmail interface. Even if i go to domain.de ....

Comment: Do you have a correct NameVirtualHost line? And you didn't answer if you have or not `ServerAlias` directives.

Comment: Hm i think i dont have a "NameVirtualHost". I tried to add a new file with `NameVirtualHost *:80` in /conf.d/ but this hasn't helped, so i removed it. Where i had to add this? The pasted code of the vhost files is the first post is the hole file-code. So no ServerAlias...

Comment: It should be before VirtualHost statements.